# Enable CSS isolation of RCL to work in blazor server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a razor class library and blazor server that consumes this library, each component in RCL has own css, after reading documentation of microsoft [ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I did the following:

1. In my razor page of blazor server I added my component: `<MyComponent />`
2. In _Host page I added link for bundeling: `<link href="Blazor.Components.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

After running the application I couldn't see the css of MyComponent.

Did I make something wrong? Can you give me some advice?. I read this [page](https://dev.to/dharsha007/net-5-0-blazor-bites-css-isolation-for-blazor-components-2c33) that follows the same approach but for Webassembly!.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [Razor class library (RCL) support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#razor-class-library-rcl-support) docs:

> When a Razor class library (RCL) provides isolated styles, the  tag's href attribute points to {STATIC WEB ASSET BASE PATH}/{ASSEMBLY NAME}.bundle.scp.css, where the placeholders are:
>
> - {STATIC WEB ASSET BASE PATH}: The static web asset base path.
> - {ASSEMBLY NAME}: The class library's assembly name.
>
> In the following example:
>
> - The static web asset base path is _content/ClassLib.
> - The class library's assembly name is ClassLib.
>
> `<link href="_content/ClassLib/ClassLib.bundle.scp.css" rel="stylesheet">`

In _Host page you should to add something like:

```
<link href="_content/YourClassLib/YourClassLib.bundle.scp.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: by referencing the dll in .NET 6, this does not work, is in _Layout.cshtml
<link href="_content/YourClassLib/YourClassLib.bundle.scp.css" rel="stylesheet" />         

but, when referencing as project, i do not need to call it manually, it works and i can inspect the file exact in this path

Do i need to include something additional to the dll from the RCL?

Comment: @Nicwin Did you find a way of doing that in .net 6? I'm currently struggling.

Comment: Hi @Robert - no. after another day-Session i decided to wait for some feedback.

Comment: Did anyone solve this? I'm running into similar issues.

Comment: If you enable CSS isolation to your asp.net/blazor .net 6.0 that $(ProjectName).styles.css should automatically include an @imports to the bundle.scp.css from the RCL.